# C# Error CS0103 The name 'originalImage' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have problem with my code, I've tryed `string originalImage = null;`.
But this not really working. Because its not taking original file name somehow..

Code:

```
 private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
        fbd.Description = "+++ Select path +++";
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
        string[] originalImage = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.JPG");

        foreach (var filename in originalImage)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);

            //DefaultCompressionJpeg(bitmap);

            VariousQuality(bitmap);
        }
    }

    string originalImage = null;

    public void VariousQuality(Image original)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = null;
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid)
            {
                jpgEncoder = codec;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (jpgEncoder != null)
        {

            Encoder encoder = Encoder.Quality;
            EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

            for (long quality = 90; quality <= 90;)
            {
                EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;

                string fileOut = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Kristen\Desktop\pilt2",  originalImage + ".jpeg");
                Debug.WriteLine(fileOut);
                FileStream ms = new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                original.Save(ms, jpgEncoder, encoderParameters);
                ms.Flush();
                ms.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Because you haven't declared/initialized `originalImage` anywhere in your code

Comment: Based on the code you have, you haven't declared `originalImage` anywhere.  You said you tried `string originalImage = null;` -- so where did you put it?  That matters.  Can you update your question to make that point clearer?

Comment: Or change the method arg name to `originalImage`.

Comment: added my code. Edited post.

Comment: You have declared a local reference to a string array (`string[]`) in the function textBox1_Click named `originalImage` but have also declared a field on your class of type `string` of the same name. While this is allowed by the compiler, it is not a best practice and can cause serious confusion and unexpected behavior. The `array[]` might be better named `originalImages` or `filenames`. Code should be self-documenting. Your code says `foreach (var filename in originalImage)`. Does an original image have multiple filenames within the context of your application? I'm guessing the answer is no.

Comment: @RobertColumbia i compress multiple images. I select image folder and function must compress image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you click eventhandler you have a local variable `string [] originalImage` which you initialize with all the filenames in some directory.

On class level you have a field `string originalImage` which you initialize with `null`.

These two elements do have nothing to do with each other, they are completely unrelated.

So in your compression method you use an `originalImage` to construct a filename. The only entity of this name known in this method is the string field of the class, which has a `null` value.

You should add a second parameter to your compression method where you pass the current filename to your method and remove the field from the class.

```
public void VariousQuality (Bitmap original, string filename) {
   ...

 string fileOut = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Kristen\Desktop\pilt2", filename + ".jpeg");

}
```

Call the method as follows

```
foreach (var filename in originalImage) { 
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename);
 //DefaultCompressionJpeg(bitmap);
    string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    VariousQuality(bitmap, fn); 
}
```

Comment: but now sayng this error `Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'filename' of 'Form1.VariousQuality(Bitmap, string)'` and this line `VariousQuality(bitmap);`

Comment: Well, if you add a parameter to a method,  you must also provide a value for it, when you call it. Sorry i did not mention that. Use the filename from your loop, but be sure to remove the path and extension.

Comment: `'Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetFilenameWithoutExtension'` ,
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'string'` and `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' `

Comment: Forgive me, if I thought you had at least basic programming knowledge or did know how to use a search engine. :-o I made a typo, it's `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Comment: Look at my post and compare the order of parameters with what you have written in your code. First the bitmap, then the filename

Comment: Sorry my bad. I thinked you just got right code. Please dont be mad about that.

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested in the comments (which they mysteriously deleted because they were definitely on to something), it *seems* like you're trying to refer to the `original` argument:

```
public void VariousQuality(Image original)
```

Just rename either that arg to `originalImage` or rename the other in your code to `original`.

Comment: Still not taking original file name